# Google Refine / Open Refine: Columns to Rows

Tags: spreadsheet, openrefine

I'm afraid this might be a somewhat simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a spreadsheet with many objects, each of which has many attributes (one per column), like this (sorry, I can't post images, so this is the best I can do):

```
OBJECT ID | PERIOD              |  COLOR       | REPRESENTATION 
       1  |  Early Intermediate | Bichrome     | Abstract
       2  | Middle Horizon      | Multicolored | Representational
```

… and I'd like each column to become a separate row — which would mean that each object would be listed a number of times. Like this:

```
OBJECT   | ATTRIBUTE
Object 1 | Early Intermediate
Object 1 | Bichrome
Object 1 | Abstract
Object 2 | Middle Horizon
Object 2 | Multicolored
Object 2 | Representational
```

I'm not seeing an obvious way to do this, and I can't find an answer here, though perhaps I'm not using the right search terms.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: For anyone who has this same question, [this](http://googlerefine.blogspot.ca/2011/09/json-code-to-transpose-important-number.html?) appears to be the way to do this. Thanks to the Open Refine folks for pointing me to this on Twitter.